# Add search module in category page

Tags: magento

I would add the search form in the category pages. The module will make researches in the same category. It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add category to Advanced Search. Some pointers here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/search_and_advanced_search/how_to_add_search_by_category_to_advanced_search

You will probably want to do it in a module rather than in a core hack...

Now put some simple form together inside a phtml file, put the layout xml together to load it on category pages. Set the search to add the current category to the search string that gets sent off to your modified 'Advanced Search'.

As for getting that category, try $this->getCurrentCategory();

Comment: I would use simple search to searching in all fields of product but in specific category.

Comment: Yes, you have the same mini form, i.e. one box, but you get it to call advanced search where the category is derived from the current category page, which is $this->getCurrentCategory()

Comment: What name should I assign to input? That in mini form it's name is "q"

Comment: I am not writing a search by category module for you right now as my boss wouldn't like it...! However, go to advanced search, type something in, see what the query string is and... take it from there.

Comment: I'm sorry. I wanted to know if there is an input to search in all fields or I should create (since this advanced search is performed only on the fields sent, i.e. name or price)